# trac-ik lib is not loding

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to install trac-ik to moveit by using apt-get in ubuntu 16.04, kinetic version. However I don't know why when I start the demo of the moveit, it keeps give me the error of:

```
The kinematics plugin (arm) failed to load. Error: Failed to load library /opt/ros/kinetic/lib//libtrac_ik_kinematics_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libmoveit_kinematics_base.so.0.9.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

when I look at the path `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib//libtrac_ik_kinematics_plugin.so.` has an addition / in  lib//libtrac_ik_kinematics_plugin.so.
I tried to delete trac_ik and install again but it still the same. It's really wired, It's all install automatically. Could someone tell me where I can modify to make this path correct? Thanks so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327798/trac-ik-lib-is-not-loding/) by [leo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33187/leo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-07-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33187/leo/) on 2019-07-06**:
My colleague doing the same installation of trac-ik but not any problems... I do believe if I reinstall the system may fix this but there was a lot thing in my computer at the moment, I won't be able to that. How can fix this issues without reinstall the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same error after installing trac_ik, solved it by:

1. Upgrade

> sudo apt-get upgrade

1. Delete devel and build
2. Rebuild your workspace

> catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [Ogunniran](https://answers.ros.org/users/34931/ogunniran/) with karma: 26 on 2020-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1